# Get XML children name, and their children with LXML returns only None

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I'm trying to parse some XML using [LXML](http://lxml.de/) in the format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ttFont sfntVersion="OTTO" ttLibVersion="2.5">

  <cmap>
    <tableVersion version="0"/>
    <cmap_format_4 platformID="0" platEncID="3" language="0">
      <map code="0x0" name=".null"/><!-- ???? -->
      <map code="0xd" name="CR"/><!-- ???? -->
```

based on the tutorial [here](http://www.rdegges.com/basic-xml-parsing-with-python-and-lxml/), but for some reason, the simple command

```
xmlFileName = "xml/myfile.ttx"
f = open(xmlFileName, "r")
s = f.read()

doc = etree.XML(s.strip())
map = doc.findtext('map')
print map
```

only returns `None`. How can I get the node name for all of `cmap`'s children (eg, `cmap_format_4`), and all of the map children?

Comment: ``findtext`` will only find the first time the ``map`` **text** appears. And from your example, you don't have the map as text/content. If you're looking for map as in the tag of the element, then use ``find`` or ``findall``

Answer (score 0):

Use `findall()` to get all the `map` children of the `cmap_format_4` node. Example:

```
for cmap_format in doc.findall('.//cmap_format_4'):
    for m in cmap_format.findall('map'):
        print m.attrib['code']
```

Prints:

```
0x0
0xd
```

Comment: Thanks so much. How can I use this with a variable (and with unknown names) number of `cmap_format_N` nodes? I would like to loop through each of the `map` nodes, but have access to their parents' names along the way.

Comment: Also, I'm getting the error `for m in doc.findall('.//cmap_format_4/map'):
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'findall'`. I'm getting my XML with `xmlFileName = "xml/BeretLTStd-Bold.ttx"` [new line] `doc = open(xmlFileName, "r")`. Should I be doing it some other way? Thanks again.

Comment: @thomas `doc` is the result of `etree.parse()` call.

Comment: Hi, do you mind taking a look at my other question? Thanks so much.

Comment: @thomas updated the answer, hope this is what you are asking about.